# Specialise partial template parameter with type argument (VC++ v140 toolset)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015

I try to build a partial template specialisation like the following (this does not make sense in this short form, but it is reduced to the problem):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class C> struct A {
    int x;
    std::basic_string<C> y;
};

template <class C, class T>
struct B { B(void) { std::cout << "default "; }; };

template<class C>
struct B<C, decltype(A<C>::x)> { B(void) { std::cout << "int "; }; };

template<class C>
struct B<C, decltype(A<C>::y)> { B(void) { std::cout << "string "; }; };

int main() {
    B<char, int>{};
    B<char, std::string>{};
    B<wchar_t, std::wstring>{};
}
```

The VC++ compiler (*v140* toolset) complains about the partial template specialisations saying that they are duplicates:

> error C2953: 'B': class template has already been defined

My first question is: is the code above standard-conformant, ie should it compile?

If I switch the toolset to *Visual Studio 2015 - Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v140_clang_c2)*, it compiles and runs with the expected output "int string string", so my assumption is that the answer to the first question is "yes", because `T` is not a non-type.

Hence the second question: Is it possible to rephrase the code such that it removes the dependency  on `C` which seems to make VC++ break?

And the third question: Is this a known problem of VC++ v140?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Comment: Aren't you missing four `class` keywords and a semicolon?

Comment: Try [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eef061c96ac4a2d8).

Answer (score 1):

That's not the syntax for [partial class template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). This is:

```
template <class T, class U>
class Traits { };

template <class T> // one template parameter
class Traits<T, decltype(A<T>::x)> { };
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

template <class T>
class Traits<T, decltype(A<T>::y)> { };
```

You also have to make `A::x` and `A::y` accessible.

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the missing class keyword and semicolon, this is an example of the explicit full class template specialization:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>   // primary template
struct is_void : std::false_type
{
};
template<>  // explicit specialization for T = void
struct is_void<void> : std::true_type
{
};
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: The problem does not exist for full template specialisations, it only occurred when I had to add the second parameter.